# Vagrant provisioning with different dependencies based on branch

Tags: vagrant

Different branches and versions of my codebase have different dependencies, e.g. master branch might be on Ruby 1.9 and use Rails 4, but some release branch might be on Ruby 1.8 and use Rails 3. I imagine this is a common problem, but I haven't really seen much about it.

Is there a clean way to detect/re-provision the Vagrant VM based on the current branch (or maybe Gemfile)?

Currently I have it set up to "bundle install" and other stuff in the provisioner, which sorta works but it still clutters the VM enviroment with the dependencies for each branch I've ever been on.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add the `Vagrantfile` and the provisioning scripts to the repository? Since they are part of the branch then, they can look like you wish.

If you often switch between branches this might not suite anymore since you would need to re-provision the vm every time you change the branch. In that case I would suggest to setup multiple vms in the `Vagrantfile` and add provisioning scripts for all the vms in parallel. Then you could do something like

```
vagrant up ruby1.8
vagrant up ruby1.9
```

... and so on.

Comment: Your first suggestion is what I'm currently doing. I was hoping something a little more elegant was possible? If at least there was a way to avoid having to redownload the ruby and gems it might not be so bad..

Comment: The second solution should work for you. I would suggest to keep vagrant/provisioning development in a separate branch and merge into the other dev branches if required. However, the basic problem that I see is that you are developing the different softwares (they are different, isn't it?) in one repo using branches. I would make 3 repos out of it. This would simplify the workflow a lot.

Comment: It's only one project, with multiple release branches. Having extra gems around doesn't hurt much, so a VM for each ruby *almost* works except that I have to worry about point releases as well (e.g. ruby 2.2.2) because it is locked in the Gemfile. Although even then maybe it's only 5, so that might be OK.

Comment: What about using `rbenv` inside the vm? Your `.bashrc` may decide which rbenv to launch by investigating the git repo in the `/vagrant` folder. (I assumed you are using the default shared folder)

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of hek2mgl answer but I would use different VM repository rather than multiple VM from the same Vagrantfile

For example I sometimes do the following :

- have the VM on an external hard drive but the project on my local drive
- I have a shell script `workhere.sh` which set the corresponding VM to use

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  export VAGRANT_CWD="/Volumes/VMDrive/..."/;
  ```

If you commit the script to your git repo, all you need to do after you checkout a branch is to do `source workhere.sh` and it'll point you to the correct VM so you can have multiple VM running in parallel

In the case you switch first time, you'll need to boot the VM and after ssh, but in the case you switch multiple times, the VM will be up and by indicating which VM you need to point too, `vagrant ssh` would connect to the correct VM.

If you leave VM up and running you would need to be cautious about IP (if you use fixed IP) and port forwarding as you could have conflict.